# Joomla:: created JText does not appear

Tags: joomla

I am working on a Joomla project where I am new to Joomla. Trying to complete the tasks in the standard way. Therefore to display "Copyrights" and "All rights reserved" I have created two JText in "en-GB.tpl_beez5.ini" file. beez5 is the template I am using.
In "en-GB.tpl_beez5.ini" file what I have created is:

```
TPL_BEEZ5_COPYRIGTHS="Copyrights ©"
TPL_BEEZ5_ALL_RIGHTS_RESERVED="All Rights Reserved"
```

In my index.php file I am calling those two JText by using following code:

```
<?php echo JText::_('TPL_BEEZ5_COPYRIGTHS');?> <company name> <?php echo JText::_('TPL_BEEZ5_ALL_RIGHTS_RESERVED');?>
```

But the problem is what I get in browser is

```
TPL_BEEZ5_COPYRIGTHS <company name> TPL_BEEZ5_ALL_RIGHTS_RESERVED
```

I really have no idea about what could be the reason for this. I tried Google but could not find anything to solve my problem.

Anything I can do to solve my problem please.

Comment: just on a side note, you have spelt it incorrectly. `COPYRIGTHS >> COPYRIGHTS`

Answer (score 4):

**Problem solved.**

It didn't work because the configuration file `en-GB.tpl_beez5.ini` which I have edited is inside `templates/beez5/language/en-GB` but I have found actual file which I have to modify is available inside `language/en-GB`

Thanks for the checking it **Lodder**

Answer (score 0):

I have just added you code to Beez 5 on my server to test and everything works perfectly:

Just a few tweaks I made such as changing © to © to it can be read by every browser

**Language Strings:**

```
TPL_BEEZ5_COPYRIGHT="Copyright &copy;"
TPL_BEEZ5_ALL_RIGHTS_RESERVED="All Rights Reserved"
```

**index.php**

```
<?php echo JText::_('TPL_BEEZ5_COPYRIGHT'); ?> Company Name <?php echo JText::_('TPL_BEEZ5_ALL_RIGHTS_RESERVED'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is not working to me at all... :(

Comment: Have you touched any of the core Joomla code or database tables?

Comment: Nop.. no any core joomla code or database tables... at the moment working with only CSS for front-end designs...